# Error Twig when I try to run Symfony 3 project on server

Tags: symfony, server, twig, symfony-3.2

I actually try to install a new project in Symfony 3.2 on my server (with Plesk).

I put PHP 7.0.17.

When I look my website in "app_dev", it's ok, but without it doesn't work.

I think there is a relation with the error when I run "`php bin/console assetic-dump --env=prod`" :

```
[2017-03-25 10:20:21] assetic.ERROR: The template "SecurityBundle:Collector:security.html.twig" contains an error: Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to Twig_Filter::__construct() must be an instance of string, string given, called in /xxx/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Extension/Core.php on line 139 and defined
[2017-03-25 10:20:21] assetic.ERROR: The template "TwigBundle::layout.html.twig" contains an error: Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to Twig_Filter::__construct() must be an instance of string, string given, called in /xxx/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Extension/Core.php on line 139 and defined
[2017-03-25 10:20:21] assetic.ERROR: The template "TwigBundle:Exception:exception.rdf.twig" contains an error: Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to Twig_Filter::__construct() must be an instance of string, string given, called in /xxx/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Extension/Core.php on line 139 and defined
[2017-03-25 10:20:21] assetic.ERROR: The template "TwigBundle:Exception:error.html.twig" contains an error: Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to Twig_Filter::__construct() must be an instance of string, string given, called in /xxx/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Extension/Core.php on line 139 and defined
[2017-03-25 10:20:21] assetic.ERROR: The template "TwigBundle:Exception:error.css.twig" contains an error: Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to Twig_Filter::__construct() must be an instance of string, string given, called in /xxx/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Extension/Core.php on line 139 and defined
[2017-03-25 10:20:21] assetic.ERROR: The template "TwigBundle:Exception:logs.html.twig" contains an error: Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to Twig_Filter::__construct() must be an instance of string, string given, called in /xxx/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Extension/Core.php on line 139 and defined
[2017-03-25 10:20:21] assetic.ERROR: The template "TwigBundle:Exception:error.rdf.twig" contains an error: Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to Twig_Filter::__construct() must be an instance of string, string given, called in /xxx/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Extension/Core.php on line 139 and defined
[2017-03-25 10:20:21] assetic.ERROR: The template "TwigBundle:Exception:exception.xml.twig" contains an error: Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to Twig_Filter::__construct() must be an instance of string, string given, called in /xxx/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Extension/Core.php on line 139 and defined
[2017-03-25 10:20:21] assetic.ERROR: The template "TwigBundle:Exception:error.xml.twig" contains an error: Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to Twig_Filter::__construct() must be an instance of string, string given, called in /xxx/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Extension/Core.php on line 139 and defined
[2017-03-25 10:20:21] assetic.ERROR: The template "TwigBundle:Exception:traces_text.html.twig" contains an error: Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to Twig_Filter::__construct() must be an instance of string, string given, called in /xxx/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Extension/Core.php on line 139 and defined
[2017-03-25 10:20:21] assetic.ERROR: The template "TwigBundle:Exception:traces.txt.twig" contains an error: Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to Twig_Filter::__construct() must be an instance of string, string given, called in /xxx/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Extension/Core.php on line 139 and defined
[2017-03-25 10:20:21] assetic.ERROR: The template "TwigBundle:Exception:exception.html.twig" contains an error: Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to Twig_Filter::__construct() must be an instance of string, string given, called in /xxx/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Extension/Core.php on line 139 and defined
[2017-03-25 10:20:21] assetic.ERROR: The template "TwigBundle:Exception:error.json.twig" contains an error: Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to Twig_Filter::__construct() must be an instance of string, string given, called in /xxx/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Extension/Core.php on line 139 and defined
[2017-03-25 10:20:21] assetic.ERROR: The template "TwigBundle:Exception:error.atom.twig" contains an error: Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to Twig_Filter::__construct() must be an instance of string, string given, called in /xxx/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Extension/Core.php on line 139 and defined
[2017-03-25 10:20:21] assetic.ERROR: The template "TwigBundle:Exception:exception.atom.twig" contains an error: Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to Twig_Filter::__construct() must be an instance of string, string given, called in /xxx/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Extension/Core.php on line 139 and defined
[2017-03-25 10:20:21] assetic.ERROR: The template "TwigBundle:Exception:exception.json.twig" contains an error: Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to Twig_Filter::__construct() must be an instance of string, string given, called in /xxx/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Extension/Core.php on line 139 and defined
[2017-03-25 10:20:21] assetic.ERROR: The template "TwigBundle:Exception:traces.html.twig" contains an error: Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to Twig_Filter::__construct() must be an instance of string, string given, called in /xxx/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Extension/Core.php on line 139 and defined
[2017-03-25 10:20:21] assetic.ERROR: The template "TwigBundle:Exception:error.txt.twig" contains an error: Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to Twig_Filter::__construct() must be an instance of string, string given, called in /xxx/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Extension/Core.php on line 139 and defined
[2017-03-25 10:20:21] assetic.ERROR: The template "TwigBundle:Exception:exception.js.twig" contains an error: Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to Twig_Filter::__construct() must be an instance of string, string given, called in /xxx/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Extension/Core.php on line 139 and defined
[2017-03-25 10:20:21] assetic.ERROR: The template "TwigBundle:Exception:error.js.twig" contains an error: Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to Twig_Filter::__construct() must be an instance of string, string given, called in /xxx/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Extension/Core.php on line 139 and defined
[2017-03-25 10:20:21] assetic.ERROR: The template "TwigBundle:Exception:trace.txt.twig" contains an error: Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to Twig_Filter::__construct() must be an instance of string, string given, called in /xxx/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Extension/Core.php on line 139 and defined
[2017-03-25 10:20:21] assetic.ERROR: The template "TwigBundle:Exception:trace.html.twig" contains an error: Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to Twig_Filter::__construct() must be an instance of string, string given, called in /xxx/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Extension/Core.php on line 139 and defined
[2017-03-25 10:20:21] assetic.ERROR: The template "TwigBundle:Exception:exception.css.twig" contains an error: Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to Twig_Filter::__construct() must be an instance of string, string given, called in /xxx/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Extension/Core.php on line 139 and defined
[2017-03-25 10:20:21] assetic.ERROR: The template "TwigBundle:Exception:traces.xml.twig" contains an error: Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to Twig_Filter::__construct() must be an instance of string, string given, called in /xxx/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Extension/Core.php on line 139 and defined
[2017-03-25 10:20:21] assetic.ERROR: The template "TwigBundle:Exception:exception.txt.twig" contains an error: Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to Twig_Filter::__construct() must be an instance of string, string given, called in /xxx/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Extension/Core.php on line 139 and defined
[2017-03-25 10:20:21] assetic.ERROR: The template "TwigBundle:Exception:exception_full.html.twig" contains an error: Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to Twig_Filter::__construct() must be an instance of string, string given, called in /xxx/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Extension/Core.php on line 139 and defined
[2017-03-25 10:20:21] assetic.ERROR: The template "SwiftmailerBundle:Collector:swiftmailer.html.twig" contains an error: Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to Twig_Filter::__construct() must be an instance of string, string given, called in /xxx/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Extension/Core.php on line 139 and defined
[2017-03-25 10:20:21] assetic.ERROR: The template "DoctrineBundle:Collector:db.html.twig" contains an error: Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to Twig_Filter::__construct() must be an instance of string, string given, called in /xxx/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Extension/Core.php on line 139 and defined
[2017-03-25 10:20:21] assetic.ERROR: The template "DoctrineBundle:Collector:explain.html.twig" contains an error: Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to Twig_Filter::__construct() must be an instance of string, string given, called in /xxx/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Extension/Core.php on line 139 and defined
[2017-03-25 10:20:21] assetic.ERROR: The template "LocationFrontBundle:Accueil/Partials/A-la-une:location.html.twig" contains an error: Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to Twig_Filter::__construct() must be an instance of string, string given, called in /xxx/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Extension/Core.php on line 139 and defined
[2017-03-25 10:20:21] assetic.ERROR: The template "LocationFrontBundle:Accueil:index.html.twig" contains an error: Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to Twig_Filter::__construct() must be an instance of string, string given, called in /xxx/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Extension/Core.php on line 139 and defined
[2017-03-25 10:20:21] assetic.ERROR: The template "LocationFrontBundle:Layout:layout.html.twig" contains an error: Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to Twig_Filter::__construct() must be an instance of string, string given, called in /xxx/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Extension/Core.php on line 139 and defined
[2017-03-25 10:20:21] assetic.ERROR: The template "LocationFrontBundle:Layout:footer.html.twig" contains an error: Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to Twig_Filter::__construct() must be an instance of string, string given, called in /xxx/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Extension/Core.php on line 139 and defined
[2017-03-25 10:20:21] assetic.ERROR: The template "LocationFrontBundle:Layout/Accueil:menu.html.twig" contains an error: Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to Twig_Filter::__construct() must be an instance of string, string given, called in /xxx/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Extension/Core.php on line 139 and defined
[2017-03-25 10:20:21] assetic.ERROR: The template "LocationFrontBundle:Layout/Accueil:header.html.twig" contains an error: Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to Twig_Filter::__construct() must be an instance of string, string given, called in /xxx/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Extension/Core.php on line 139 and defined
[2017-03-25 10:20:21] assetic.ERROR: The template "LocationFrontBundle:Layout/Accueil:layout.html.twig" contains an error: Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to Twig_Filter::__construct() must be an instance of string, string given, called in /xxx/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Extension/Core.php on line 139 and defined
[2017-03-25 10:20:21] assetic.ERROR: The template "LocationFrontBundle:Layout/Autre:layout.html.twig" contains an error: Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to Twig_Filter::__construct() must be an instance of string, string given, called in /xxx/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Extension/Core.php on line 139 and defined
[2017-03-25 10:20:21] assetic.ERROR: The template "LocationBackBundle:Default:index.html.twig" contains an error: Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to Twig_Filter::__construct() must be an instance of string, string given, called in /xxx/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Extension/Core.php on line 139 and defined
[2017-03-25 10:20:21] assetic.ERROR: The template "WhiteOctoberBreadcrumbsBundle::breadcrumbs.html.twig" contains an error: Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to Twig_Filter::__construct() must be an instance of string, string given, called in /xxx/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Extension/Core.php on line 139 and defined
[2017-03-25 10:20:21] assetic.ERROR: The template "LexikFormFilterBundle:Form:form_div_layout.html.twig" contains an error: Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to Twig_Filter::__construct() must be an instance of string, string given, called in /xxx/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Extension/Core.php on line 139 and defined
[2017-03-25 10:20:21] assetic.ERROR: The template "LiipImagineBundle:Form:form_div_layout.html.twig" contains an error: Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to Twig_Filter::__construct() must be an instance of string, string given, called in /xxx/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Extension/Core.php on line 139 and defined
[2017-03-25 10:20:21] assetic.ERROR: The template ":default:index.html.twig" contains an error: Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to Twig_Filter::__construct() must be an instance of string, string given, called in /xxx/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Extension/Core.php on line 139 and defined
[2017-03-25 10:20:21] assetic.ERROR: The template "::base.html.twig" contains an error: Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to Twig_Filter::__construct() must be an instance of string, string given, called in /xxx/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Extension/Core.php on line 139 and defined
```

When I search a solution, I find that I have to put PHP 7.0.17.
But it's already done.

Can someone help me ?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Plesk PHP - versions have different PHP - executables:

```
/opt/plesk/php/5.2/bin/php -v
/opt/plesk/php/5.3/bin/php -v
/opt/plesk/php/5.4/bin/php -v
/opt/plesk/php/5.5/bin/php -v
/opt/plesk/php/5.6/bin/php -v
/opt/plesk/php/7.0/bin/php -v
/opt/plesk/php/7.1/bin/php -v
```

Pls. use the FULL command path, due to the fact, that your commmand "php ..." without the full path will be executed with your standart, vendor PHP version ( i.e.: /usr/bin/php )